# Couchbase php sdk 2 Generic Error

Tags: php, couchbase

I am trying to test a couchbase connection in php v5.5 with the 2.0.7 cb sdk. I am getting the following out put when I run the code below. The server I am trying to connect to is remote and I do not have the the cb server app installed on this machine. I do have the C Lib for CB.

```
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_add: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_add: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
[warn] event_pending: event has no event_base set.
Generic error
```

Code:

```
<?php
$cb = new CouchbaseCluster('couchbase://ip.add.re.ss', 'user', 'pass');
try{

    $b = $cb->openBucket('default');
}
catch( CouchbaseException $e){
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

edit:
Here's what I have installed for libevent.

```
# yum list | grep libevent
libcouchbase2-libevent.x86_64              2.5.0-1.el6                  @couchbase
libevent.x86_64                            1.4.13-4.el6                 @base
libevent-last.x86_64                       2.0.21-4.el6.remi            installed
libevent.i686                              1.4.13-4.el6                 base
libevent-devel.i686                        1.4.13-4.el6                 base
libevent-devel.x86_64                      1.4.13-4.el6                 base
libevent-doc.noarch                        1.4.13-4.el6                 base
libevent-headers.noarch                    1.4.13-4.el6                 base
```

edit2:
I installed couchbase C sdk and PHP on another near identical machine and it works.

edit3: 
I have tried reinstalling the packages but nothing changed.

Comment: What version of `libevent` do you have installed?

Comment: @Paddy see edit for more detail. `libcouchbase2-libevent.x86_64              2.5.0-1.el6                  @couchbase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove `libevent-last` as it was conflicting with the couchbase version.

More details are available on the couchbase forums.
https://forums.couchbase.com/t/lib-event-error-with-c-sdk-php/4063/2